# T v{} initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, uniform-initialization

I'm reading the C++11 standard, but can't figure out whether

```
T x{};
```

is value-initialized or default initialized (automatic storage). 
It *does* say pretty clearly that:

> 10 An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.

And that

> 11 If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized;

But all I can find about `T x{};` is that:

> The initialization that occurs in the forms T x(a);
>   T x{a};
>   as well as in new expressions (5.3.4), static_cast expressions (5.2.9), functional notation type conversions (5.2.3), and base and member initializers (12.6.2) is called direct-initialization.

and

> If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).

I'm new to diving into the level of reading the standards. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is indeed covered by your quote:

> If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).

Skipping down to 8.5.4 List-initialization. Here I have paraphrased/omitted some points that don't pertain to the case of `T x{}`:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>`  [...]
> - Otherwise, [if the list is not empty and it matches a constructor]
> - Otherwise, [if the list has a single element]
> - Otherwise, [if `T` is a reference type]
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.
> - Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

The first point, *aggregate initialization* was in C++03 as well; in that case `T x{};` is the same as `T x = {};`.

For the second point "T is a class type with a default constructor", it is *value-initialized* which means calling the default constructor.

If `T` is a primitive type then the second-to-last point applies and it is *value-initialized* again.

Going back to the *aggregate initialization* case, in 8.5.1/7 there is:

> If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there is no brace-or-equal-initializer, from an empty initializer list (8.5.4).

The *brace-or-equal-initializer* refers to an initializer provided inline in the class definition. If that isn't present then it is initialized as if the member had been initialized with `{}` (so, this logic is recursively applied for each aggregate member).

For example,

```
struct T
{
     int a;
};
```

then `T x {};` leads to `a` being initialized as if it were `int a{};` , which is value-initialization since `int` is a primitive type.

Comment: Thanks for finding this - I read *list-initialization* and thought it implied use of > 1 element.

Comment: Looking at this, I feel both awe and dread of C++ at the same time.

Comment: @Vilx Heh yeah. There is a lot of stuff to know. The list-initialization for non-aggregates was added in C++11... it solves some problems (search "most vexing parse") but adds a few new weird corner cases

Answer (score 8):

Although Matt McNabb has already covered this, I will add that if you have trouble navigating through the standard, it doesn't hurt to check out [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com). Their section on [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) breaks it down pretty well.

Essentially, like your standard quote says, `T x{};` refers to an:

> initialization of a named variable with a brace-enclosed list of
>   expressions or nested lists (*braced-init-list*).

And:

> The effects of list initialization of an object of type T are:
>
> - If the braced-init-list is empty and T is a class type with a default constructor, value-initialization is performed.
>
> [...]
>
> - Otherwise, if the braced-init-list has no elements, T is value-initialized.